# Consuming RESTful WCF with multiple parameters (Json)

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I am in a process of consuming the RESTful WCF that I've created. I was able to consume the service with all the method (GET/PUT/DELETE/POST) with multiple parameters. These are some of the methods that I was able to consume at the client side:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetEmployeePost")]  
[OperationContract]  
string GetEmployeePost(List<Employee> listEmployee);  

[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetEmployeePost/{userId}")]  
[OperationContract]  
string GetEmployeePost2(List<Employee> listEmployee, string userId);
```

And these are my code at the client side to consume the methods given above:

This is my collection.

```
public class Employee  
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }  
    public string LastName { get; set; }  
}
```

And these are the method to consume the WCF REST method.

```
static void ConsumeWcfRestPostMethod()  
{  
    var listEmployee = new List<Employee>();  
    listEmployee.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, FirstName = "Eireen", LastName = "Kim" });  
    var paramContent = Serialize(listEmployee);  
    var result = PostMethod(_baseAddress + "GetEmployeePost", paramContent, "POST");  
    Console.WriteLine(result);  
    Console.ReadLine();  
}  

public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)  
{  
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());  
    var ms = new MemoryStream();  
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);  
    string retVal = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());  
    ms.Dispose();  
    return retVal;  
}  

public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)  
{  
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();  
    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));  
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());  
    obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);  
    ms.Close();  
    ms.Dispose();  
    return obj;  
}  

static string PostMethod(string url, string msg, string method)  
{  
    string result = string.Empty;  
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);  
    var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);  

    myHttpWebRequest.Method = method;  
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";  
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;  

    using (var request = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())  
    {  
        request.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  
        request.Close();  
    }  

    var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();  
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))  
    {  
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();  
        myHttpWebResponse.Close();  
    }  
    return result;  
}
```

Now my question is. How can I consume the method below???

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetEmployeePost3/{userId}")]  
[OperationContract]  
string GetEmployeePost3(List<Employee> listEmployee, List<EmployeeDetail> listEmployeeDetail, string userId);
```

This method has 2 List and a string parameters..

Please HELP...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I already solved this problem of mine using WebChannelFactory.

Comment: Nice code..this certainly seems like it would be nice to use and you have total control of what's going on ...good stuff, thanks for sharing the way you're doing this, especially the generic methods above.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this problem of mine using **WebChannelFactory** on the clientside..
visit the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)!